# How to access webcam in Safari and IE? Are there alternatives to getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, safari, getusermedia

I am currently accessing webcam in javascript, then streams to browsers using getUserMedia, [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) shows that Safari and Internet Explorer 11 and above are not able to access getUserMedia.

I use this to check if there is a webcam,

```
navigator.getUserMedia  =   navigator.getUserMedia ||
                            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.msGetUserMedia;
```

Then I display using this

```
if (navigator.getUserMedia){
    //document.getElementById("webcam").style.display = "block";

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            video = document.getElementById("video"),
            videoObj = { "video": true },
            errBack = function(error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
            };

        // Put video listeners into place
        if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
            navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                video.src = stream;
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }
        else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }
        else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }
        // Trigger photo take
        document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
            canvasToDataURLString = canvas.toDataURL();
            var blob = dataURItoBlob(canvasToDataURLString);
            base64result = canvasToDataURLString.split(',')[1];
            //console.debug(base64result);
            document.getElementById("base64result").innerHTML = base64result;

        });
    }, false);
}
```

Or there simply is no way of accessing webcam using IE and safari?
I understand there are limitations in Chrome as the webpage has to be accessed from a secure origin.

1. I wonder if I am doing it wrongly...
2. I want to know if there are any other alternatives to getUserMedia!

Thank you and please be kind, I have already tried googling and nth much came out, I am just seeking for alternatives, if it is really impossible, then ok.

Comment: have you got solution yet ? me too stuck in the same problem please let me  know if you found any solution for Safari and IE

Comment: @MohdSadiq Nope I have not even tried the suggested solution

Answer (score 0):

The end user should use the Temasys WebRTC plugin for Safari and IE to enable  WebRTC in each of the browsers https://skylink.io/plugin/.

Comment: Hence, no way to access WebRTC without 3rd party plug-ins on the end-user side?